# Making backend solution with Datakit?

Tags: ios, web-services, backend, custom-backend

I want to run my own service with datakit for iOS, as alternative for parse, there is some good tutorial how to setup it?

Answer (score 3):

On github repository there is everything you need to set up the server.
For free you can try it on localhost, or heroku or ec2(with bitnami node.js image) with mongohq.
If you are looking for an example of the usage of the framework, then start with [ParseKit](https://github.com/OneMoreThing/ParseKit).